# Ad-mob Ads not showing on either simulator or device

Tags: ios, admob, cocos2d-x, ads

In my cocos2d-x project i have done the following code for showing ads on devices/simulator.

```
    GADInterstitial *gAdInterstitial; = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];
    gAdInterstitial.adUnitID = @gAdUnitID;
    NSLog(@"Add Unit Id %@",gAdInterstitial.adUnitID);
    //AdMob
    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
//        request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:GAD_SIMULATOR_ID, nil];
//    request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:GAD_SIMULATOR_ID,@"122189cf8ed3c83551f5df0585f4694f410f5041", @"eb26e6181da2a2da39f3410cd29c4c2c26ac19a6", nil];
    request.testing = YES;
    request.testDevices = @[GAD_SIMULATOR_ID];
    [gAdInterstitial loadRequest:request];
    gAdInterstitial.delegate = self;
```

This code is been done in the rootviewcontroller class and in appcontroller class for iOS. the problem is that it is not showing any ads even on the network working.

Comment: try setting `gAdInterstitial`'s delegate before `loadRequest:`

Answer (score 0):

check you Unit Id and also at
 request.testDevices = @[GAD_SIMULATOR_ID];
specify your simulator id or device id.

Its not important to test with testing set to YES, you can run with production settings but avoid clicking on ads.